# how to stream the audio and play that audio

Tags: android, audio-streaming

i want to play mp3 file which is streamed mp3 file. i tried below  link example

http://blog.pocketjourney.com/2008/04/04/tutorial-custom-media-streaming-for-androids-mediaplayer/ 
but the bellow error is coming

```
 02-04 20:22:48.960: ERROR/PlayerDriver(31): Command PLAYER_PREPARE completed with an    error or info PVMFErrResource
 02-04 20:22:48.970: ERROR/MediaPlayer(425): error (1, -17)
 02-04 20:22:48.989: WARN/PlayerDriver(31): PVMFInfoErrorHandlingComplete
 02-04 20:22:49.089: DEBUG/dalvikvm(425): GC freed 4622 objects / 982864 bytes in 120ms
 02-04 20:22:49.350: ERROR/com.Boodang.StreamingMediaPlayer(425): Error updating to newly loaded content.
 02-04 20:22:49.350: ERROR/com.Boodang.StreamingMediaPlayer(425): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
 02-04 20:22:49.350: ERROR/com.Boodang.StreamingMediaPlayer(425):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
 02-04 20:22:49.350: ERROR/com.Boodang.StreamingMediaPlayer(425):     at com.Boodang.StreamingMediaPlayer.createMediaPlayer(StreamingMediaPlayer.java:210)
 02-04 20:22:49.350: ERROR/com.Boodang.StreamingMediaPlayer(425):     at com.Boodang.StreamingMediaPlayer.transferBufferToMediaPlayer(StreamingMediaPlayer.java:239)
 02-04 20:22:49.350: ERROR/com.Boodang.StreamingMediaPlayer(425):     at com.Boodang.StreamingMediaPlayer.access$3(StreamingMediaPlayer.java:219)
 02-04 20:22:49.350: ERROR/com.Boodang.StreamingMediaPlayer(425):     at com.Boodang.StreamingMediaPlayer$2.run(StreamingMediaPlayer.java:160)
 02-04 20:22:49.350: ERROR/com.Boodang.StreamingMediaPlayer(425):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
 02-04 20:22:49.350: ERROR/com.Boodang.StreamingMediaPlayer(425):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 02-04 20:22:49.350: ERROR/com.Boodang.StreamingMediaPlayer(425):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 02-04 20:22:49.350: ERROR/com.Boodang.StreamingMediaPlayer(425):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
 02-04 20:22:49.350: ERROR/com.Boodang.StreamingMediaPlayer(425):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 02-04 20:22:49.350: ERROR/com.Boodang.StreamingMediaPlayer(425):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
 02-04 20:22:49.350: ERROR/com.Boodang.StreamingMediaPlayer(425):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
 02-04 20:22:49.350: ERROR/com.Boodang.StreamingMediaPlayer(425):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
 02-04 20:22:49.350: ERROR/com.Boodang.StreamingMediaPlayer(425):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

so please tell me what i will do and i hope there is better way to do this one . so please tell me how to stream the mp3 file and play the mp3 file.

Thank you.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

First, that blog post is nearly three years old. Never use Android blog posts from that long ago.

Second, at least through Android 2.2, streaming MP3 files was not supported over RTSP. I think it works over HTTP.

Beyond that, make sure the URL you are using actually is reachable from your device or emulator. For example, you need the `INTERNET` permission in your app, your emulator needs to have Internet access, etc.

In the future, you might consider supplying source code, as a stack trace alone is usually insufficient to get assistance from anyone.